# What is the derivative of the norm of a unit vector?

Tags: matrices, vectors

The derivative of $v^Tv$ with respect to v is $$\frac{\partial (v^Tv)}{\partial v}=2v.$$Suppose v is a unit vector, then $v^Tv=1$ and $$2v=\frac{\partial (v^Tv)}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial (1)}{\partial v}=0.$$However, $v$ is not a zero vector. So what is wrong of my derivation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to take into account that the derivative does not know  that  $v^Tv=1$. The equation $\frac{\partial (v^Tv)}{\partial v}=2v$ is true for generic vectors, not for the subset of vectors that also obeys $v^Tv=1$

Comment: The derivative **really** is $2v$, but the normalization condition works to ensure that any infinitesimal change $(dv)$ is constrained to be in a direction orthogonal to the current direction of $v$, i.e.  $\,v^Tdv = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: @greg I agree, you phrased it more accurately than I did.